# Blender 3.0 installation error

Tags: error, windows, installation

I'll cut to the chase, when trying to install blender I get a popup from windows telling me it is an untrusted app with expired certificates. Error code is (0x800B010A)

There is no way to bypass this or use administrator abilities to install blender anyways.

installation I'm using is blender-3.0.0-stable+v30.f1cca3055776-windows.amd64-release.msix from the official site, on the daily builds page.

The popup window looks very odd, as it's not styled like any other error page I've seen, but my anti-virus isn't throwing a fit about it other than denying the installation.

Here's an image of the popup;
[image: Blender Installation Error Popup Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR version

You download the MSI**X** file. I suggets you to use either MSI installers or just the portable ZIP to avoid this issue.

### Explanation

The issue with MSIX is that, while it is safer to use than MSI, it requires an up to date signature from the software author. If the Blender Fundation hasn't updated the signature yet, there's nothing you can do about it.
Meanwhile MSI considers signature only "recommended but not necessary".

[MSI vs MSIX: Practical Side-by-Side Comparison](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-limitations.html)